# Visitor IP and counter not update

Tags: php, mysqli

I have created one website, now in that i get visitor ip address from  php $_SERVER, now what i want , if same user will visit website more than once,so only counter need to be increased instead of ip. But when i ran php application it not allowing any ip to insert so please guide me what wrong i have done. my code is below,

```
    <?php
    $username="root";
    $password="";   
    $servername="localhost";
    $database="xyz";
    $tableName="xyz";
    
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    
    $ip = ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $query2=mysqli_query($con,"select cntr,ip from counter")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query2))
    {
        echo $row['ip'];
        echo $row['cntr'];
        
        if($row['ip']== $ip)
        {
            mysqli_query($con,"update counter set cntr = cntr+1 where ip = '$ip'");
        }
        else
        {
            mysqli_query($con,"insert into counter (ip,date,cntr) values ('$ip',now(),1)");
        }
    }
    $_SESSION['status'] = true;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is logically incorrect:
Let's say that you have 100 rows with unique IP in counter table. In your loop you are inserting 99 rows and updating only one row that corresponds to an existing IP ($ip), if no corresponding IP is found, you insert 100 rows with the same IP ($ip).

First, i would check if IP exist in table counter, like this:

```
$sql = "select count(*) as cnt from counter where ip = '$ip'";
// check if IP is already stored
$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, $sql));
```

Then proceed with the insert or update:

```
if($check['cnt'] > 0) { 
    // ip is present, update record (your query is fine)
} else {
    // ip not present, insert new record (your query is fine)
}
```

With this method there is no need to check if table is empty.
Also you neeed to be sure that the field cntr is not initialized as NULL, otherwise the +1 will not work on your update query.